# Error al convertir elementos de una lista en Python a int

Tags: python, lista

tengo un problema al querer obtener un elemento de una lista y convertirlo a `int`
tengo la siguiente Función:

```
def SearchMatches(list1,list2):
for i in list1:
    yield [pos for pos ,j in enumerate(list2) if i==j]
```

El código anterior obtiene las posiciones coincidentes entre las listas, que en ejemplo se muestra así.

```
list1 = ['Address','Email','Password'] 
list2 = ['Name','Address','Email','Password','Country']

objectList = ["Name","Address","Email","Password","Country"]

matches = list(SearchMatches(list1,list2))
for item in matches:
 print(item)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero convertir esos elementos a `int+` para poder hacer los siguiente:

```
for item in matches:
print(objectList[item])
```

como si fuera esto

```
print(objectList[0])
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Espero que me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SearchMatches()` según entiendo, es una función que te retorna las posiciones en `List2` de los elementos de la `list1` que se encuentren en ella. No me queda muy claro, por qué luego con esos valores intentas acceder a una tercer lista, pero supongo que está afuera de tu problema inicial. Tampoco resulta claro que intentes usar una función generadora (con `yield`) para inmediatamente transformar todo en un lista con: `matches = list(SearchMatches2(list1,list2))`

De cualquier forma, si buscas que `SearchMatches()` sea una función generadora, mi sugerencia es que en vez de retornar un lista, simplemente retornes cada una de las posiciones de los elementos coincidentes:

```
def SearchMatches(list1,list2):
  for i in list1:
      for pos, j in enumerate(list2):
        if i == j:
          yield pos
```

Ahora si, podrías hacer algo así:

```
for item in SearchMatches2(list1,list2):
  print(objectList[item])
```

Y por cierto, el error `list indices must be integers or slices, not list` lo que te está indicando es que estás intentando acceder por índice a una lista con un valor que es tipo lista, cuando se espera que sea un entero o un slice.

Answer (score 0):

> list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tu variable `matches` contiene listas de un elemento, es decir que es una lista de listas en vez de una lista de enteros. En caso de que su contenido siempre sea de un solo elemento, la forma más sencilla sería acceder al primer elemento de la lista (que sería el único elemento en la misma), así:

```
for item in matches:
    print(objectList[item[0]])
```

Sin embargo, yo sugeriría simplificar un poco tu código aprovechando los métodos de las `listas` y `sets`:

```
list1 = ['Address','Email','Password'] 
objectList  = ['Name','Address','Email','Password','Country']

valueMatches = list(set(list1).intersection(objectList ))

print(valueMatches)##Si quieres los valores que se repiten

indexMatches = [objectList .index(index) for index in valueMatches ]

print(indexMatches)##Si quieres los indices en objectList  que se repiten
```